# Vue.js - What is the self modifier

Tags: events, vue.js

I am learning Vue.js. Currently, I'm trying to understand eventing. In Vue, there are [Event Modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers). I understand the purpose of all of them except for the `self` modifier. What is the `self` modifier? It seems like the `stop` modifier does the same thing as `self`. When would I use `self`?

Thank you for any help. I feel like i have to be misunderstanding something. I just don't see the purpose of `self`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a parent node and child node are registered with same type of event then when that type event dispatches then handlers of parent and child are called.

Here is an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9o24m93/).

Try removing `self` from click event modifier of the parent div then click on the child div.

1. First the child handler is called.
2. Parent handler is called.

   ```
   <div class="parent" v-on:click="log('from parent')">
     Parent
     <div class="child" v-on:click="log('from child')">
       Child
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

If you put back `self` modifier and clicking on the child div doesn't call the parent handler.

Answer (score 8):

Let's i explain difference.

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="root" v-on:click="log('root')">root
        <div class="parent" v-on:click.self="log('parent')">Parent
            <div class="child" v-on:click="log('child')">Child
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do you know about event phases?

```
Capture (event.eventPhase = 1)
Target (event.eventPhase = 2)
Bubbling (event.eventPhase = 3)
```

By default if you add event listener for element it will work in bubbling mode.

If you click on **child** in example, you will get output:

```
child
root
```

Modificator **self** say: 'If user click on me (my area or borders), please trigger handler'

If you remove **self**:

```
<div class="parent" v-on:click="log('parent')">
```

and click on **child**, you will get output:

```
child
parent
root
```

If you add **stop**:

```
<div class="parent" v-on:click.stop="log('parent')">
```

and click on **child**, you will get output:

```
child
parent
```

You will not get **root**, because **stop** cancel event bubbling **(event.stopPropagation)**.

If you will use **self** it doesn't stop bubbling!

Answer (score 3):

As the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) says:

> only trigger handler if event.target is the element itself
>
> i.e. not from a child element

So if you want to capture an event, which is not being triggered from anywhere in child component, but when clicking on the whole component, you can use this modifier.